# Original UITableView is shown over UITableView of the results using Search Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am adapting my App for support both iOS7 and 6.

I am using a Search Bar over a Table View for filter data to show.

But when my search is filtered, appear the table view with filtered data above the original data table view, so they are overlapped.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Attach 2 images:

1. Without search.

[image]

2. With search (as you can see, table view are overlapped)
   [image]

Edited:

Adding Data Source methods

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    return arregloFiltrado.count;
}else{
    return arreglo.count;
}
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CeldaLista" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = celdaLista;
    self.celdaLista = nil;
}


if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1] setText: /*Name and surname*/];
    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2] setText: /*Other properties*/];

    if ([[arregloFiltrado objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"] == nil) {
        [(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:4] setImage:/*No image*/];
    }
    else{
        [(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:4] setImage:/*Photo*/];
    }
} else {
    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1] setText:/*Name and surname*/];
    [(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2] setText:/*Other properties*/];

    if ([[arreglo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"] == nil) {
        [(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:4] setImage:/*No image*/];
    }
    else{
        [(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:4] setImage:/*Photo*/];
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Something more?

Comment: Paste your table view datasource code

Comment: Are you using two tableView?

Comment: can you please show your code ?

Comment: If you are using UISearchDisplayController instead of UISearchBar it shows a second table over the original one. If you provide transparent background cells for search results, that's the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a UISearchDisplayController it has it's own UITabelview.  So as you begin to search the search display controller superimposes the search interface over the original view controller’s view, as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You may want to set the background colour of the table cells or the entire table view for the table provided by the UISearchDisplayController so that is not transparent.

Alternatively you could filter your original table by implementing a UISearchBar and its associated delegate methods:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

  //As the user enters search text filter the array that provides data to the UItableView you wish to filter
}
```

Investigate the searchbar delegate here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Thanks

TG

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//color of search result table
    }
```

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! But translucent effect of iOS7 is lost… Is there another way to solve this?